# How to stop the program creating two windows unnecessarily?

Tags: python, tkinter

So, im trying to create this project for an assignment and it might be because im newer to tkinter or very tired and cant pick up on it or see where im going wrong, but i cant seem to get the program to stop opening two windows. I'm really not sure where to go with this, I just need the gray bar and the text and buttons to be on the same window, and hopefully once i find out why this is happening, i can correct it in the future.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Canvas
window=Tk()
canvas=Canvas(window, width=1366, height=768)

class SeaofBTCapp(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container=Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames={}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class StartPage(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label=Label(self, text="start page", font=("Verdana", 12))
        label.place(x=0, y=0)
        #label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

        button = Button(self, text="Visit Page 1",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))

        button.pack()

        button2 = Button(self, text="Visit Page 2",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button.pack()


        #self.design(parent)

    #def design(self, parent):
        topbar=canvas.create_rectangle(0,0, 1366, 30, fill="gray")

        canvas.pack()


class PageOne(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label=Label(self, text="Page One", font=("Verdana", 12))
        label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        button1=Button(self, text="back to home",
                          command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))

        button1.pack()

        button2=Button(self, text= "page 2",
                          command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()


class PageTwo(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = Label(self, text="page two", font=("Verdana", 12))
        label.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

        button1 = Button(self, text="back to home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button1.pack()

        button2=Button(self, text="page one",
                          command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button2.pack()


window=SeaofBTCapp()
#canvas=Canvas(window, width=1366, height=768)
window.title('Floor Plan')
window.geometry("1366x768")
window.configure(bg="white")
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're explicitly creating two windows. First, you do `window=Tk()` which creates a window. Next, you do `window=SeaofBTCapp()`. Since `SeaofBTCapp` inherits from `Tk` it is also a window.

To only create one window, remove `window=Tk()` and the canvas you put inside it.

If you want `topbar` to be at the top of the window, create the canvas inside of `__init__`.

```
class SeaofBTCapp(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = Canvas(window, width=1366, height=768)
        container=Frame(self)

        canvas.pack(side="top", fill="x")
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        ...
```

In the other classes you can then reference it via the `controller`.

```
topbar=controller.canvas.create_rectangle(0,0, 1366, 30, fill="gray")
```